# Resources for impedance matching networks

Tags: rf, antenna, passive-networks, impedance-matching

I am working on my first hobby PCB design project that includes RF components. On one hand, I have a 2.5GHz WiFi signal and an 868Mhz LoRa signal.

I copied the matching networks from the reference designs of the used components respectively and everything works just fine. However, I would like to dive a bit deeper into the topic and I am looking for some resource that I can read into, a book mostly, or some application note.

I am familiar with the basics of impedance matching, I can use a Smith chart for example, but there are components or rather blocks of components that I don't really know. What I am looking for is some kind of a document that details the design of matching networks using passive SMD components on a PCB. There is an output impedance, there is a load and an impedance matching network is built between the two, but not only an RC or LC component. I would like to learn about the stages of the matching networks, like the DC block capacitor, what value it should have, how the PCB features affect the value, where should I use a CLC pi filter, what values it should have, when to use a band stop filter, etc.

I don't necessarily want to design a matching network, but I would like to understand it and be able to reason about the values of the componenst.

I have found AN5457 from ST, which is pretty good and goes into sufficient details, but it only describes that single impedance matching scenario. But I am looking for similar resources, maybe some of you know such books or documents that I could not find so far.

Comment: I have a few links on my basic website to impedance matching: http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20home.html but, what you are asking for is a shopping request and, maybe it's also soliciting opinions because clearly there will be different viewpoints on this. If you stated a precise example and learned from that it would be acceptable to the site rules of course.